# Change date format in comments

Tags: comments, datetime

How can I change the date format in my comments?

Right now it looks like this:

> Sat, 09/01/2012 - 12:00

I want it to look like this:

> Saturday, September 1, 2012

I was able to achieve this in page.tpl.php in a section where I just display the date, but have no idea where to do this so it works for my comments too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to do it sitewide, you can edit the definitions at admin/config/regional/date-time/formats

You can also add your own formats there, and then use them in [`format_date()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/format_date/7) similar to what [@Epok outlined](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41440/change-date-format-in-comments#41447).

Comment: This is the correct answer. There is no need to change the theme, when there is a global setting.

Answer (score 5):

When you watch your `comment.tpl.php` you see that you can override some variables with `template_preprocess_comment()`

I don't know if it's the best way but it works fine for me.
You have to put this function in `template.php`

```
function mytheme_preprocess_comment(&$variables){
  $variables['created'] = date('l, F d, Y', $variables['elements']['#comment']->created);
  $variables['changed'] = date('l, F d, Y', $variables['elements']['#comment']->created);
}
```

[image: comments date]
There is a post about this on [Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/1075692)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use format_date() function:
format_date($timestamp, $type = 'medium', $format = '', $timezone = NULL, $langcode = NULL)

Please note UNIX timestamp is timezone blind.

```
function YOURTHEME_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {      
  $variables['created'] = format_date($variables['elements']['#comment']->created, 'custom', 'l, j F Y h:i A');
}
```