# Changing time format for comments in template file

Tags: 7, theming, nodes

I'd like to only change the time formatting for comments that we have attached to forum posts in Drupal 7. I have a custom template setup and to get the time that the comment was created.

Right now to do this I use print($created);

And I get Thu, 12/05/2013 - 07:20

I know how to change the date formats at admin/config/regional/date-time/formats, but how do I use one of those formats when I print the date in my template file?

I see in the template file it suggests "Preprocess functions can reformat it by calling format_date() with the desired parameters on the $comment->created variable." But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: MPD and Epok answered this question before - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41440/change-date-format-in-comments

Comment: I saw that answer, but it doesn't say which date format to change. Which one is assigned to a comment by default?

Comment: It's actually "Medium", but the main question is how to connect a custom date to the comments. That I think has to be done with php.

Comment: function YOURTHEME_preprocess_comment(&$variables){
$variables['created'] = format_date($variables['elements']['#node']->created', 'custom', l, F d, Y', );
}
would go in your template.php file. Replace the part l,F,d,Y with your custom date formatter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change date format in comments](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41440/change-date-format-in-comments)