# Change date format in Advanced Forum

Tags: 7, datetime, nodes

I have changed date formats in Views and in Drupal core Date settings, but I'm still seeing wrong date format on forum (for example in node where conversation is) at class *.forum-posted-on*.

In template file advanced-forum.myforumtemplate.post.tpl.php:

```
<?php print $date ?>
```

How to change date format?

Comment: see [Change date format in comments](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41440/change-date-format-in-comments)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to alter the date through `template_preprocess_node()` and `template_preprocess_comment()` in your theme. The first preprocess is used for the forum nodes (initial forum post) and the latter for comments (replies).

Add the following code to your theme's `template.php` file:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->type=='forum') {
    // Custom date.
    $variables['date'] = format_date($variables['node']->created, 'custom', 'M d Y, H:i:s');
    // Use date format provided by Drupal:
    // $variables['date'] = format_date($variables['node']->created, 'short');
  }
}

function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_comment(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->type=='forum') {
    // Custom date.
    $variables['date'] = format_date($variables['node']->created, 'custom', 'M d Y, H:i:s');
    // Use date format provided by Drupal:
    // $variables['date'] = format_date($variables['node']->created, 'short');
  }
}
```